# I need to create buttons dynamically. But each button needs a different code

Tags: c#, winforms, button, reset

I need to program about adding rooms. Its like this, when I press a Add button, there has to show a label, a textbox, a checkbox and a button(to reset the others). But when I dynamically create a button and press reset, it will reset the other textboxes and checkboxes also.

What do I have to type in my 'New button event'?

Can you guys help me out?

//this is my code

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Label label = new Label();
    int count = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
    label.Location = new Point(10, (25 * count) + 2);
    label.Size = new Size(40, 20);
    label.Name = "lbl" + (count + 1);
    label.Text = "Kamer " + (count + 1);
    label.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);

    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    int count1 = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count;
    textbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 25 * count1);
    textbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);
    textbox.Name = "textbox" + (count1 + 1);
    textbox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(textbox);

    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
    int count2 = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList().Count;
    checkbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 25 * count2);
    checkbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);
    checkbox.Name = "checkbox" + (count2 + 1);
    checkbox.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(checkbox);

    Button button = new Button();
    int count3 = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().Count;
    button.Location = new Point(10, (25 * count3) + 2);
    button.Size = new Size(140, 25);
    button.Name = "button" + (count3 + 1);
    button.Text = "Reset";
    button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
    button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Click);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the Button_Click method?

Comment: First, you should be using a `UserControl` instead of hard-coding all that control initialization. Then, that `UserControl` should have a method that clears/resets the fields/controls you want. Finally, when you add a new instance of the `UserControl` to your form and connect it to the button (or if the button is in fact in the `UserControl`, even easier), just have the button call the reset method on the _specific_ `UserControl` instance you want to reset.

Comment: Note that without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it won't be possible to provide any sort of specific advice or answer.

Comment: That is the problem, i'm just an beginner and I tried different codings, but none of them worked for me. So I'm just asking this, I need to create a textbox that I can clear with a Reset button. It hasn't be so difficult :D.